# Inconsistency of Tag definitions across the various Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Has anyone noticed that there is a distinct lack of consistency in the definitions of the same *Tag*, across the various sites under the Stack Exchange umbrella?

Cases in point:

1. The definition of *konqueror* in **Ask Ubuntu** is different from that in **Super User** which, in turn, differs from that in **Unix & Linux**
2. The definition of *konsole* in **Stack Overflow**, **Unix & Linux**, **Ask Ubuntu** and **Super User**

Taking *konsole* as an example:

On **Super User** the excerpt is "Terminal emulator for the K Desktop Environment (KDE)" and the main definition is empty.

On **Ask Ubuntu** the excerpt is "Konsole is the terminal emulator for the K Desktop Environment." and the main definition is:

> Konsole is an X terminal emulator for the KDE platform, allowing users
>   to have a convenient way to use the command line. Aside from providing
>   a way to use a powerful shell, Konsole also offers features that make
>   it easier or more pleasurable to work in the command line, such as
>   profile management, scrollback, and color schemes, including
>   translucency for effects.
>
> ```
> X Terminal emulator
> Makes using the command line easier
> Use different profiles for different tasks
> Set scrollback limit and save contents to file
> Click on links to open in user's default web browser
> Open current path in user's file manager
> Translucent background available when desktop effects are enabled
> ```

There are many more... *emacs* for example.

Now I understand that, obviously, in some forums the same word may actually possess a different meaning, but where it is obviously the same word/definition pair, in the cases where the context is clearly the same, is there not a way of making them homogenous? It would be nice to be able to have a *inherit definition* mechanism, or something like that.

One may suggest to do it manually, but it is not that simple as some peer reviewers will not accept certain definitions. I have tried and failed. As the reviewers are different people, we end up with a "left hand not knowing what the right hand is doing" situation.

Maybe it is my OCD but it is starting to get on my nerves...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Thoughts?  Consider the following:  |||||/|||

Comment: I would kindly ask the down voter to explain what was wrong with my post, Otherwise I may continue to make the same mistake in future posts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Greenonline the downvoted likely simply disagreed with the proposal. It's a well written question I assure you.

Comment: OK, many thanks for the feedback. Much appreciated. I was going to ask a question, on Meta, along the lines of "_Should down voters not have to explain themselves?_", but I have seen that [it has been asked already](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes), and "sort of" understand the downvote system better, now.

Comment: @Won't - I don't quite understand what you are getting at? Is your comment relevant to my question, or is it a typo?

Comment: OCD test.  You passed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tag wikis are not Wikipedia-lite.  They are a tool for explaining how that tag should be used on that site.  It's entirely unsurprising for that to vary between sites.  Even if a particular topic is on topic on different sites, different aspects of that topic will no doubt be on topic or emphasized, different information may be relevant to people asking questions on that subject, etc.

I would in fact be much more surprised to see tags having virtually identical tag wikis on different sites.

As tempting as it can be to try to treat tag wikis as an encyclopedia entry for that topic, that's simply not what they're there for.  They're there to tell you *how to use that tag on that site*.

Answer (score 9):

Stack Exchange *sites* (and notice that I didn't use the term forums, for they are not forums) live separately in the network. They interact only by sharing users and the occasional migration, but for the most part, each is left on its own to build its own collection of knowledge. That's what we want.

Tag wikis are no different.

Different sites may have different standards or goals, subtly at least, that tag wikis aim to accomplish. The cultures could be different.

It's worth noting that some guidelines on setting tag wikis suggest using them to list *how* that tag is to be used, not just what it means. You can imagine how 134 sites with different cultures could require some space with that.

Beyond that, and I know you mentioned this, one tag could mean wildly different things on two different sites. Imagine [planes](/questions/tagged/planes) as interpreted on [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com) versus [Travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com). Classifying each and every tag wiki as "applicable on these two sites, but not that one" would require intimate knowledge of their use on each site, and just generally, a ton of effort. It's not really worth it. Sure, there are a few sites with similar subject matter, but they make up pretty small sets of the whole network. Allowing the automatic sharing of tag wikis would turn pretty hectic, with all those relationships in mind.

If you see a tag wiki that's awesome, and a tag wiki that's not-so-awesome, it can be worth merging them on the latter site. There was a meta post about that recently, but I don't remember if it was here or on MSO. But doing this in bulk just isn't practical, and doesn't really solve a problem.